# SharePoint document preview

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to find out if document preview can be shown when we mouse over on some link or document in Sharepoint online like the one we get in Sharepoint Search results page?

can we show the document preview on mouse over a document ? Is this possible in SharePoint online ? If so, how can it be done ?